# PCRE version of subRegex

Tags: regex, haskell

I need to make a version of the function [`subRegex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex.html#v%3asubRegex) which works with `Text.Regex.PCRE`.

The version of `subRegex` provided in the `Text.Regex` module is [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/latest/doc/html/src/Text-Regex.html#subRegex):

```
{- | Replaces every occurance of the given regexp with the replacement string.

In the replacement string, @\"\\1\"@ refers to the first substring;
@\"\\2\"@ to the second, etc; and @\"\\0\"@ to the entire match.
@\"\\\\\\\\\"@ will insert a literal backslash.

This does not advance if the regex matches an empty string.  This
misfeature is here to match the behavior of the the original
Text.Regex API.
-}

subRegex :: Regex                          -- ^ Search pattern
         -> String                         -- ^ Input string
         -> String                         -- ^ Replacement text
         -> String                         -- ^ Output string
subRegex _ "" _ = ""
subRegex regexp inp repl =
  let compile _i str [] = \ _m ->  (str++)
      compile i str (("\\",(off,len)):rest) =
        let i' = off+len
            pre = take (off-i) str
            str' = drop (i'-i) str
        in if null str' then \ _m -> (pre ++) . ('\\':)
             else \  m -> (pre ++) . ('\\' :) . compile i' str' rest m
      compile i str ((xstr,(off,len)):rest) =
        let i' = off+len
            pre = take (off-i) str
            str' = drop (i'-i) str
            x = read xstr
        in if null str' then \ m -> (pre++) . ((fst (m!x))++)
             else \ m -> (pre++) . ((fst (m!x))++) . compile i' str' rest m
      compiled :: MatchText String -> String -> String
      compiled = compile 0 repl findrefs where
        -- bre matches a backslash then capture either a backslash or some digits
        bre = mkRegex "\\\\(\\\\|[0-9]+)"
        findrefs = map (\m -> (fst (m!1),snd (m!0))) (matchAllText bre repl)
      go _i str [] = str
      go i str (m:ms) =
        let (_,(off,len)) = m!0
            i' = off+len
            pre = take (off-i) str
            str' = drop (i'-i) str
        in if null str' then pre ++ (compiled m "")
             else pre ++ (compiled m (go i' str' ms))
  in go 0 inp (matchAllText regexp inp)
```

When I run this with `Text.Regex.PCRE` imported, I get

> Not in scope: 'mkRegex'

There is a function called [`makeRegex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v%3amakeRegex) in the RegexLike module but it has a different type and this is where I'm stuck.

**Edit - Solution**

Create new `mkRegex` function like so:

```
-- | Makes a regular expression with the default options
mkRegex :: String -> Regex
mkRegex s = makeRegexOpts opt defaultExecOpt s
  where opt = (defaultCompOpt + compCaseless) -- or other options
```

Comment: Do you know why there hasn't been a patch for this after all this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mkRegex` is defined in `Text.Regex` in the regex-compat package. You could try just copying its source. I'd be surprised if it worked completely without change, but perhaps not too much is necessary.

Comment: Thank you, so simple, and yet it works with a little modification.